How to create edgetoedge mode of Flutter like Android Native
How to get perfect fullscreen (edge to edge) mode for flutter?
With native, it's very easy to do the image below, the target is the statusbar, the system only displays text, icons, and the bottom navigation is the same, but the app's color remains intact.
portrait image
landscape image
Flutter has a little problem with horizontal screens, you can also see the picture below
portrait image
landscape image
I used flutter code for edge to edge with options like :
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: false,
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: false,
));

Note: if try with emulator please create with deviceframe and in a notch device (like pixel 6a), I use api 34

It is important to apply it properly:

Apply the EdgeToEdgeWrapperWidget for each page as a root widget
If you use SafeArea as a parent widget of some container widget with a background, you should use SafeArea(bottom: false, top: false)
It's better to avoid using SafeArea as a parent widget for a container widget with a background

For the solution below I used code:

https://github.com/rydmike/adaptive_theme_demo/blob/8d8587e759ee40f430f9a4a54a4415de8b0cf916/lib/theme/custom_overlays_style.dart#L8
https://github.com/rydmike/adaptive_theme_demo/blob/8d8587e759ee40f430f9a4a54a4415de8b0cf916/lib/ui/screens/home_screen.dart#L60

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// A quick and easy way to style the navigation bar bar in Android
/// to be transparent and edge-to-edge, like iOS is by default.
SystemUiOverlayStyle customOverlayStyle(
    {final bool transparentStatusBar = false}) {
  unawaited(SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge));
  final statusBarColor = transparentStatusBar ? Colors.transparent : null;
  return SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: statusBarColor,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  );
}

class EdgeToEdgeWrapperWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool transparentStatusBar;

  EdgeToEdgeWrapperWidget(
      {super.key, this.transparentStatusBar = false, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: customOverlayStyle(transparentStatusBar: transparentStatusBar),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}


